# Remove all instances of a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to remove all instances of a specific value from a list and then shift remaining list items down. The code works in some cases but not in others. For example:

```py
print(myremove([7, 'B', 1, 8, 3, 'B'], 6, 'B')) # Gets what I want 
print(myremove(['C', 'C', 7, 'C', 4, 'C'], 6, 'C')) # Does not
```

One of the things I want to do is remove all instances of the item and then move all the remaining elements down.

```py
   def myremove(mylist, elements, item):
        for i in range(elements):
            if mylist[i] == item:
                 mylist[i] = None
                 elements-= 1

        for i in range(elements):
            if mylist[i] is None:
                for j in range(i, elements):
                    mylist[j] = mylist[j + 1]
                    mylist[elements] = None

        return mylist
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use a simple pythonic list comprehension:

```py
vals = ['C', 'C', 7, 'C', 4, 'C']
droplist = [6, 'C']
[x for x in vals if (x not in droplist)]
```

### Modified `myremove()` Function

```py
def myremove(vals, droplist = None):
    if droplist is None:
        droplist = [None, ]
    return [x for x in vals if (x not in droplist)]

print(myremove([7, 'B', 1, 8, 3, 'B'], droplist=[8, 'B']))
print(myremove(['C', 'C', 7, 'C', 4, 'C'], droplist=[6, 'C']))
```

**Output**:

```
[7, 1, 3]
[7, 4]
```